# Regex to match exact number of occurence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do I create a regex to exactly match `{{ variable }` and ignore the `{{ variable }}`.

this what I have

```
text.match(/{{[^}]+}/g
```

but it's also matching `{{ variable }}` instead of just `{{ variable }`.

Comment: Add a lookahead, `(/{{[^}]+}(?!})/g`

Comment: @capchuck Because he tries to match only one `}` at the end

Comment: {{[^}]+}(?!}) This should work. https://regex101.com/ Try out this link. It helps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to detect `{{ variable }` as valid and ignore {{ variable }}

You have to verify the end of the string using `$`

**Regex Needed** `/{{[^}]+}$/g`

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/LAAb5b/1)

**Visulization**

[image]

```js
const input1 = "{{ variable }";
console.log(input1.match(/{{[^}]+}$/g));

const input2 = "{{ variable }}";
console.log(input2.match(/{{[^}]+}$/g));
```

**EDIT**

If you want to detect `{ variable }}` as valid and ignore `{{ variable }}`

You have to verify the start of the string with `^`, also you have to check for negative lookahead for `{{` using `(?!{{)`

**Regex Needed** `/(?!{{)^{[^}]+}}$/g`

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/AH23UL/1)

**Visulization**

[image]

```js
const input1 = "{ variable }}";
console.log(input1.match(/(?!{{)^{[^}]+}}$/g));

const input2 = "{{ variable }}";
console.log(input2.match(/(?!{{)^{[^}]+}}$/g));
```

Comment: thank you. this works! what about detecting `{ variable }}` ? trying to catch broken `{{ variable }}` format.

Comment: @J.Doe updated the answer

Comment: so sorry for asking so much but im having a hard time wrapping my head around regex. the solution above matches `{ variable }}` but its not matching if there are characters before `{ variable }}` like `hey { variable }}`

Comment: the idea is to find `{ variable }}` in a block of text. thanks again